# A function that always returns the positive of the input.

Tags: functions

So I have been thinking about if you could possibly create a function which always returns the positive of a number.

To clarify, say I input $-4$, this function will output $4$.

$$f(-5)=5$$
$$f(5)=5$$
$$f(n)=f(-n)$$
**It always outputs the positive of the input.**
I have tried playing around with this to try and find this function, but with no success. I also tried to prove it didn’t exist, again fruitless.

My question, therefore is:

> Is there such a function? (By this I mean an algebraic function without modulus or any other “cheat”. You know what I mean.)
>
> If not, how can one prove it does not exist?

Thanks.

Comment: There obviously is such a function, but I suppose you’re looking for some formula for it. $f:x\mapsto\sqrt{x^2}$.

Comment: That function is normally denoted by $|\cdots|$ e.g. $|-3| = 3$. As @AMD writes, for real numbers you have $|x| = \sqrt {x^2} $ but there's seldom need for an explicit formula like this.

Comment: @amd I thought of that. However $\sqrt{x^2$} returns positive or negative x. I what it to provide solely the positive

Comment: @md2perpe I realise there is seldom need for this, I was just curious. And also is there a different way other that |x| as I consider that to be “cheating” to be honest. (I don’t have a better word for “cheating”.)

Comment: @roskiller *"However $\sqrt{x^2}$ returns positive or negative x."* No! The square root only returns positive values.

Comment: @Sobi $-2*-2=4$ $\sqrt{4}=+-2$ Surely?

Comment: @roskiller The square root function is defined only to return a positive value. If it returned two different values, it would not be a function. See [Square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root).

Comment: @roskiller. There is often need for the absolute value, and even more so for generalizations to vectors (which I assume that you don't know about). What I referred to was that there's seldom need for the formula $|x| = \sqrt{x^2}.$

Comment: @roskiller. $\sqrt{x}$ is defined for $x \geq 0$ as the unique $t \geq 0$ such that $t^2 = x.$ Thus, for example $\sqrt{4} = +2,$ not $\pm 2.$

Comment: Here are a couple of articles on Wikipedia about this topic and generalizations:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnitude_(mathematics)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)

Comment: Thanks, we haven't gotten to this at my school. At least, I now know what the Abs button on my calculator does!